# How to Return Data from connection.QueryFirst in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, dapper, asp.net-core-3.1

Hi Guys I am learning ASP.NET core
how to return data from SQLquery to json
current i am getting everything null in result

MY Controller Code snippet

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetData")]
public DataMaster GetData()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("EmployeeDBConnection")))
    {
        var param = new DynamicParameters();
        //  param.Add("@prodtype", prodtype);
        return connection.QueryFirst<DataMaster>(" Select producttype,servicetype,servicesubtype,count(*) from master_table group by producttype,servicetype,servicesubtype");
    }

}
```

Response i am getting

```
{"callId":null,"callstartdate":null,"callstarttime":null,"calltype":null,"producttype":null,"servicetype":null,"callertype":null,"servicesubtype":null}
```

[image: Please Check Response from SQL Query]

when i execute query in Database i am getting following  response , how should return this response through API controller
please help.

Comment: Expected behaviour. According to your image the first row is all nulls. I would then expect QueryFirst to return a response of all nulls.

Comment: What *do* you want to return? The first non-null row? Or all results? Perhaps all non-null results?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i want all the row except Null row? how should i do that can you help

Comment: Use `Query` and add `WHERE product type is NOT NULL` in the query

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using `dapper` & [`QueryFirst`](https://dapper-tutorial.net/queryfirst) will `Execute a query and map the first result to a dynamic list.`.

You should use [`Query`](https://dapper-tutorial.net/query) : `The raw SQL query can be executed using the Query method and map the result to a strongly typed list.`

Use `Query<DataMaster>` instead of `QueryFirst<DataMaster>` and change return type to `IEnumerable<DataMaster>`.

As per `comment` you didn't get `Count`. I guess you are having `Count` property in `DataMaster` then you need to provide `alias` for `count` in `query` as `count(*) AS Count` then it will bind correctly.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetData")]
public IEnumerable<DataMaster> GetData()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("EmployeeDBConnection")))
    {
        var param = new DynamicParameters();
        //  param.Add("@prodtype", prodtype);
        return connection.Query<DataMaster>(" Select producttype,servicetype,servicesubtype,count(*) AS Count from master_table group by producttype,servicetype,servicesubtype");
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the Help i tried ,it worked partially , but i didn't get Count row in response , can you help??

Comment: I've updated answer and if you want count to bind in `Count` property in `DataMaster` then you need to provide `Count` `alias` for `count(*)` in `query` as `count(*) AS Count` then it will bind correctly.